# Submit form on change of input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a form with multiple input checkbox fields. I want to trigger form submit on change in any of the checkbox without submit button.

```
<form action="" method="get">
  <input type="checkbox" name="p[]" value="1">
  <input type="checkbox" name="p[]" value="2">
  <input type="checkbox" name="p[]" value="3">
</form>
```

How it can be done with jQuery?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could hook to the `change()` event of the checkboxes, then fire a `submit()` on the parent `form`, like this:

```
$('form input').on('change', function() {
    $(this).closest('form').submit();
});
```