# onchange form input grabs value and submits form

Tags: javascript, php, html

[click to see the toggle input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ULaTf.jpg)

I have a form input for item quantity, it's formatted to have toggles for increasing and decreasing the value

```
<input name="quantity" type="text" class="form-control text-center" id="quantity" value="<?php echo $crow[ 'quantity' ];?>" />
```

How could I use javascript to run a function on change or on click and grab it's value and submit a form?

Thanks for your help

I now have

```
function changeQuant(){
     var x = document.getElementById("quantity").value;
     document.getElementById('fquant').submit();
}
```

and the form submits on change

```
<form action="cartplusone.php" method="post" id="fquant" >                  
   <td class="input-qty"><input name="quantity" type="text" class="form-control text-center" id="quantity" onchange="changeQuant()" value="<?php echo $crow[ 'quantity' ];?>" /></td>
   <input name="newqval" type="hidden" id="newqval" value="">
</form>
```

How do I now best get the var x value into the hidden form field?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Submit form on change of input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38738034/submit-form-on-change-of-input-field)

Comment: You can set a value of a input element the same way you get it. So something like document.getElementById("newqval").value = x;

Comment: ok, this works great now for the first item in the cart, but not the second item or third, only ever the first, I guess because all onchange input fields will be the same values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use onchange

In your input add this `onchange="myFunction()"`

Following is an example with input type number

```js
 function myFunction(){
     var x = document.getElementById("quantity").value;
     console.log(x);
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="quantity" onchange="myFunction()"/>
```

Comment: great! I've party used your code and edited the question with my final issue, getting var x in the forms hidden field, it now submits ok onchange

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're searching this:

```
<script>
$('#quantity').on('change', function() {
  alert($(this).val());
})
</script>
```

Note: This solution requires JQuery!

Comment: Dont forget that this solution needs jquery. You have mistake. not `this.val()`, but `$(this).val()`

Comment: $('#quantity') isn't it ?