# How do we use OnSubmit event with Form.create

Tags: antd

Can anyone suggest me how do we use the onSubmit event in this form?

```
<Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
```

fiddle - https://codepen.io/jaison-james/full/rojypw

Comment: What the specific issue you're facing?

Comment: As per my requirement, this approach is ok for me because I would like to updates some area as per the value from the fields change, same time if user click on the submit button I need to call an event like onSubmit

Comment: So I want to know only how would like to use onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} method with this aproch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Worth to note that `onFieldsChange`, `onValuesChange` are the options for `hoc`: `Form.create({onFieldsChange, onValuesChange})`, when `onSubmit` should be applied directly to `<Form onSubmit={...}>`. There is no [`onSubmit` option for hoc available](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/blob/master/components/form/Form.tsx#L18).

What you can do is - define `onSubmit` handler in `<Form>`, and call the parent handler passed via props. Here is an example of calling parent handler only in `success` case, however you can easily change it to call it in any case:

```
const CustomizedForm = Form.create({
  onFieldsChange(props, changedFields) {
    // ... and other stuff
  },
})((props) => {

  const { getFieldDecorator, validateFields } = props.form;

  // this will be called on every submit
  const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    validateFields((err, values) => {
        console.log('Received values of form: ', values);
        if (!err) {
            props.onSubmit(values); // call the parent submit
        }
    });
}

  return (
    <Form layout="inline" onSubmit={onSubmit}>
      // ... form content
    </Form>
  );
});

class Demo extends React.Component {

  // ... other stuff

  // define handler
  handleFormSubmitSuccess = (values) => {
    console.log('values are ok', values)
  }


  render() {
    const fields = this.state.fields;
    return (
      <div>
        <CustomizedForm
           {...fields}
           onChange={this.handleFormChange}
           onSubmit={this.handleFormSubmitSuccess} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Demo />, mountNode);
```

Comment: I am refering this demo - https://ant.design/components/form/#components-form-demo-global-state Here I want to add a submit event

Comment: @Jaison are you asking about this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38738034/submit-form-on-change-of-input-field?

Comment: @Jaison is your question about how to trigger submit event in a html form manually?

Comment: Thanks for your replay. Did you check the example I had posted? it's showing how to use methods like onFieldsChange , onValuesChange etc. It will meet my requirement, also I want to include onSubbmit along with it.

Comment: @Jaison, sure I checked your examples, but it doesn't help me to understand what the `particular` issue you're trying to solve. However, I updated answer, hope it's more helpful now.

Comment: Maybe my English is bad, Could you pls fork this fiddle and add onSubmit in it, also please alert the value with this example. https://codepen.io/jaison-james/full/rojypw

Comment: @Jaison, your english is perfect! I seems to finally got your problem, and updated answer (sorry, but I prefer to store codebase here).

Comment: Thanks a lot, finally you reached me. I think this is what I am looking for, I will implement in the real project and get back to you with as an accepted answer soon, Thanks once again.

Comment: I have tested your code in a live scenario, need slight changes like below, otherwise, there will be a infinite update try and get an error for every field change. So try to change like const onSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        validateFields((err, values) => {
            console.log('Received values of form: ', values);
            if (!err) {
                props.onSubmit(values); // call the parent submit
            }
        });
    }

Comment: @Jaison, make sense

Comment: One more quick help need, I want to know is possible to get state value inside, like I would like to add a loading={this.state.posting} for the submit button after submission. Any idea how?

Comment: @Jaison, according to current implementation - the api call will be in `this.handleFormSubmitSuccess`, right? So there you'll change the state, and pass `isLoading` down to `CustomizedForm`, and there you'll apply it your button. I'd do it something like this.